# Why does not the reload() WebView when you change the position of touch

Tags: java, android

Good evening! Why does not Reload() by changing the touch position. After all, the code seems correct. From the code, I think you will understand what I need. Preferred is the easiest way to work around this problem, I just do not understand Java.

```
package com.example.pack.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    float mX;
    float mY;
    float Start;
    float Fin;
    View rl;
    WebView web;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);
        web.loadUrl("http://example.com/page.html");
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        if (Start < Fin) {
            new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    web.reload();
                }}, 1000, 1000);
        }

        rl = (View) findViewById(R.id.rl);
        rl.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        mX = event.getX();
        mY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
             Start = mY;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Fin = mY;
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

In advance thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going wrong here. When you don't assign default values to floats they default to 0.0, so in your case `Start` and `Fin` both start out at 0.0. In Android `onCreate` is called when your Activity is created, which means that it only gets called once when you launch you app. That means when your `onCreate` is called Start and Fin are both 0.0, so `Start < Fin` is false so you never create the timer.

Comment: Put the if containing the timer code under where you set Start and Fin

Comment: No. I'm not going to "write full code." We're here to help, not do it for you.

Comment: You do not do anything for me. Are you ready to write working code. If I myself could solve the problem, I would not write here. I thought 3 hours to change something but in the shuffle. I want to understand how the whole mechanism. If you write code, I can more or less figure out what's what. And thus (provessionalnymi tips) I do not get it. Thank you.