# How to call its own method

Tags: java, android

It does not work method start () that I have not tried all else fails. How do I solve this problem? If you can please reply capacitive. Thank you in advance!!!

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        mX = event.getX();
        mY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
             Start = mY;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Fin = mY;
                break;
        }

        if (Start < Fin) {
            start();
        }

        return false;
    }

    public boolean start() {
        Text.setText("dfdfdfdf");
        web.reload();
        return true;
    }
```

It would be wonderful if I have explained in more detail my previous question, so he - [Why does not the reload() WebView when you change the position of touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35779527/why-does-not-the-reload-webview-when-you-change-the-position-of-touch)

Comment: How to call method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713643/how-to-call-a-method-in-java

Comment: When you say *...does not work method start()*, you mean you don't know  why it's not being called or an error occurs during its call? Because if it is the first one, perhaps it's due to the fact that `Fin` is less or equal to `Start`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (Start < Fin) {
    this.start();
}
```